# Concatenation with 'in' keyword gives false results

Tags: python, string, boolean, concatenation

Can someone please explain why concatenating a string and a bool (as a result of using the 'in' keyword) will return a value of False, rather than giving a type error?

```
>>> var1 = "fish"

>>> var2 = "fi"

>>> print("True that " + var1 in var2) # str + bool returns False not TypeError
**False**

>>> print("True that ", var1 in var2) # str, bool works with comma method
True that  False

>>> print("True that " + var2 in var1) # str + bool returns False not TypeError
**False**

>>> print("True that ",var2 in var1) # stre , bool works with comma method
True that  True

>>> print(var2 in var1)
True

>>> type("True that ")
<class 'str'>

>>> type(var2 in var1)
<class 'bool'>
```

[image: python code using concatenation with bool]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `+` operator has a higher precedence than the `in` operator, so:

```
"True that " + var1 in var2
```

is effectively

```
("True that " + var1) in var2
```

which consequently returns `False` with `var1` being `'fish'` and `var2` being `'fi'`.

You would have to enclose `var1 in var2` in parentheses if you want the `+` operator to raise `TypeError`:

```
"True that " + (var1 in var2)
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense now!  Thank you so much.  I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

You've got your precedence wrong. `a + b in c` is parsed as `(a + b) in c`, not as `a + (b in c)`. There's no string+bool concatenation happening.

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate your response.  Makes perfect sense now.